# mySQL Substring(String, Start, Length) Not Resulting in Correct Substring

Tags: mysql, substring

I am trying to get the city substring of an HouseAddress EX: '1808  FOX CHASE DR, GOODLETTSVILLE, TN'

In this case the city will be GOODLETTSVILLE

When I call the substring function

Substring(HouseAddress, Locate(',' , HouseAddress) + 1, Length(OwnerAddress) - 3) AS City FROM housing_data;

It keeps resulting in 'GOODLETTSVILLE, TN', rather than just 'GOODLETTSVILLE'.

I even checked sure Length(OwnerAddress)-3 is snippeting the ', TN' part of by running a SELECT SUBSTRING(HouseAddress, LENGTH(HouseAddress)-3) AS Test FROM housing_data;

I can't find out what's wrong and have been trying for an hour. I just want to know why this doesn't work when my other substring functions work fine?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(HouseAddress, LENGTH(HouseAddress)-2, LENGTH(HouseAddress)) AS STATE FROM housing_data; -- Retrieves the State Perfectly OK 'TN'

SELECT SUBSTRING(HouseAddress, 1, LOCATE(',', HouseAddress)-1) AS STREET FROM housing_data;
-- Retrieves the Street Perfectly OK '1808  FOX CHASE DR'

SELECT SUBSTRING(HouseAddress, LOCATE(',', HouseAddress) + 1, LENGTH(HouseAddress) -3) AS CITY FROM housing_data; -- Doesn't work, result is GOODLETTSVILLE, TN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substring_index, is a bit more comprehensive.

Thsi wuld only work, if one of the parts don't have acoma in it

> ```
> SET @a =  '1808 FOX CHASE DR, GOODLETTSVILLE, TN'
> ```

> ```
> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@a,',',1),SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@a,',',-2),',',1),SUBSTRING_INDEX(@a,',',-1)
> ```
>
> ```
> SUBSTRING_INDEX(@a,',',1) | SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@a,',',-2),',',1) | SUBSTRING_INDEX(@a,',',-1)
> :------------------------ | :------------------------------------------------ | :-------------------------
> 1808 FOX CHASE DR         |  GOODLETTSVILLE                                   |  TN
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2037aeaea8b5818a024ac54e1321bba6)*

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know why this doesn't work when my other substring
> functions work fine?

The length of the string `'1808 FOX CHASE DR, GOODLETTSVILLE, TN'` is `37`, so the expression `Length(OwnerAddress) - 3` evaluates to (37 - 3 =) `34`.

The substring of the string `'1808 FOX CHASE DR, GOODLETTSVILLE, TN'` that starts right after the first `,` (this is what `Locate(',' , HouseAddress) + 1` returns) and extends to the next 33 chars (so that 34 chars are included) is `' GOODLETTSVILLE, TN'` (less than 34 chars because the end of the string is reached).

I suspect that you think that the 3d argument of `Substring(String, Start, Length)` which is *Length*, refers to the length starting from the beginning of the string, but this is not so.
The *Length* starts from the position defined by the 2nd argument *Start*.